# Datalabels plugin throws error when using scriptable option

Tags: chart.js

I have a doughnut chart. I'm using chartjs-plugin-datalabels. For the backgroundColor I'm using the following config:

```
plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        backgroundColor: function(context) {
          return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
        }
}
```

Based on the [docs](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/options.html#scriptable-options), the background color property should permit scriptable options.

I am receiving the below error:

```
error TS2322: Type '(context: Context) => string | string[] | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | ChartColor[]' is not assignable to type 'string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | (string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern)[] | ((context: Context) => string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern)'.
```

I'm using the following libraries versions:

```
"chart.js": "^2.8.0",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.6.0",
```

Comment: I think the problem is that `context.dataset.backgroundColor` is an array, since the function is called for each data, probably using the index will help, try something like this `return context.dataset.backgroundColor[context.dataIndex]`

Comment: @FranciscoSoares It worked. Answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pie chart defines an array of `backgroundColor` for each dataset in it and the function is called for each datalabel on the chart, you will need a way to tell which color in the array the function should use, probably using the index will do the trick.

Try something like this:

```
return context.dataset.backgroundColor[context.dataIndex];
```